# CSS - :after doesn't position correctly when used somewhere else

Tags: css, css-position

I have been trying for hours now, but I can't seem to find a solution.
I have a div with :after that puts a crown on the div. It works correctly on my status:
[image: o]
But it doesn't position correctly on forums:
[image: i]
Here's my code:

```
.crown:after {
background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/32/crown-gold-icon.png") no-repeat;
left: -5px;
border: solid transparent;
content: "";
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
border-width: 10px;
margin: -23px -5px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-26deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-26deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-26deg);
}
```

I've searched everywhere on Google, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Do you have position:relative to .crown?

Comment: I don't. This happens then I try to use position:relative: http://i.imgur.com/zfCYUZc.png @koningdavid

Comment: Can you include the code for crown (HTML + CSS) or better yet, a link to the page that's causing issues?

Comment: Does "crown" have position:relative? It should.

Comment: Probably it would be better to set this pseudo-element on the immediate avatar container, not the outer div? E.g. `.crown .avatar-container:after { ... }` (replace ".avatar-container" with the real class used in your code, and also add `position: relative` to it).